# django-admin runserver error (DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE not set )

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following error when trying to run

> django-admin runserver

```
PS C:\Users\gasgu\PycharmProjects\djangodennisproj\devsearch> django-admin runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gasgu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\gasgu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\gasgu\PycharmProjects\djangodennisproj\venv\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\gasgu\pycharmprojects\djangodennisproj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\gasgu\pycharmprojects\djangodennisproj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\gasgu\pycharmprojects\djangodennisproj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\users\gasgu\pycharmprojects\djangodennisproj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\gasgu\pycharmprojects\djangodennisproj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\gasgu\pycharmprojects\djangodennisproj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 68, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "c:\users\gasgu\pycharmprojects\djangodennisproj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\gasgu\pycharmprojects\djangodennisproj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I have done a clean installation with a virtualenv, then I didi pip install django, created the project and do the runserver.

I'm running this from pycharm community and I read that I should also set an enviroment variable called DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and I should put my project.settings as value. I did that and I still get the error.

I've also tried the same process from outside pycharm and just with command line I still get the same error. is there something I'm doing wrong?

Also as a note: if I do "python manage.py runserver" it does start the server. but I don't know if this is the way it should be done.

Comment: Try with `django-admin runserver --settings=mysite.settings` (change mysite.settings with your settings)

Comment: I get a "no module named 'devsearch' "  (the name of the project where the settings is)

Comment: Based from that error, it seems your the project is not in the python path. Try to add it there based on [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings)

Comment: It is as you say, and Brian answered, "python manage.py" is Django's recommended command-line utility as per the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/). If it works then stick with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your should always use the manage.py utility after first creating the project with django-admin, basically they are the same thing but manage.py have the setting/configurations for that project..so issues like this can be avoided. if your aim of using it is more specific..please notify

Comment: no, I'll stick with manage.py  I read the other use in one tutorial and my dumb brain forgot about the manage.py altogether, and couldn't figure out why projects I had already built were not working. thank you, I'll continue with the recommended one

Comment: oh common...don't be too hard on yourself, it was a necessary mistake, hopefully now you do have a better understanding on it function....read more from the official doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/